# C++ architechture for simple static data

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have some static data in my C++ project similar to:

```
static const int kCount = 10000;
static int data[kCount];
```

I also have some methods that control access to this data. For example:

```
// returns count of occurences of n in data
static int getCount(int n);
```

What's the proper code architechture to use in this situation?

I'm currently using a namespace (getCount isn't static) but I'm guessing a more experienced C++ programmer could come up with a better design. I've considered a class with all static methods. However, after doing some research it sounds like a namespace is the preferred way to go.

Another detail: some of the methods that operate on `data` should talk to a delegate object. I'm currently using something like `IMyData` that contains a few pure virtual functions. Then I have `static IMyData *delegate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't consider Mocking, then simply use a namespace to hold the functions. E.g.

```
namespace DataCounter {
  const int kCount = 10000;
  int data[kCount];

  // returns count of occurences of n in data
  int getCount(int n);
};
```

Then you can call function like `DataCounter::getCount()`.

If you want to make the code more testable by other component, consider your `IMyData` as an interface, implement it as `TMyData`, and mock it (e.g. gmock) by `IMyDataMock`.